# 301 redirect in Azure ASP.Net Core website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, web-config, redirect

Google is getting confused about which page to index, even though it is all nicely explained in the sitemap.

I created a redirect rule in web.config to redirect traffic from naked to www and this works great

```
 <rule name="Redirect to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
```

I am trying to create a second rule to redirect domain/home/index and domain/index to root but am not able to. Below doesn't work. I tried a few variations with different regex in pattern fields, but nothing is working.

```
    <rule name="Redirect index" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com/home/index" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick.
This converts URL to lowercase, redirects domain/home/index and domain/home to domain and domain/home/something to domain/something. Also adds www to naked domain.

Perhaps this should be a default behaviour?

Please let me know if there's a better way

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Convert to lower case" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect index" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="home/index" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect home" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="home" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect home2" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="home/*" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET Core(MVC6), we can use custom `Middle Ware` to achieve this.

Here is a simple demo for your reference.

First, create a `Middle Ware` class. According to your requirement, i have created it for you as below:

```
using ASPNETCore.Test;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ASPNETCore.Middleware
{
    public class MyMiddleware
    {
        private RequestDelegate _nextDelegate;
        private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate nextDelegate, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _nextDelegate = nextDelegate;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;        
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            string requestURL = httpContext.Request.Path.ToString().ToLower();

            //redirect domain/home/index and domain/home to domain
            if (requestURL.Contains("/home/index")||requestURL.EndsWith("/home"))
            {
                httpContext.Response.Redirect("/");
            }
            // redirect domain/home/something  to domain/something
            else if (requestURL.Contains("/home/"))
            {
                Regex reg = new Regex("/home/(.+)");
                Match match = reg.Match(requestURL);
                string value = match.Groups[1].Value;
                httpContext.Response.Redirect("/"+ value);
            }else{

                await _nextDelegate.Invoke(httpContext);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Then we can use it in `Configure` method in `Startup` class as below:

[image]

I have tested it and it worked. Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Does this have any advantages over web.config? Web.config approach seems much simpler...

Comment: @under if your web app is not hosted in IIS, how do we use Web.config? Since we choose ASP.NET Core, why not run it in Linux for better performance?

Comment: If running on linux and apache you could use .htaccess for redirection.

Comment: @under Redirects should be managed by application and not web server. Also Web.config is for ASP.NET MVC and not ASP.NET MVC CORE.

Answer (score 2):

In ASP .NET Core 3.1 I have used successfully quite simple lines of code to redirect non-www to www by utilizing:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        // redirect non-www to www website 
        app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRedirectToWww()
        );
```

`RewriteOptions` should have possible list of custom rules as mentioned in another posts.

I refer to the official Microsoft Doc [URL Rewriting Middleware in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-5.0) where is explained in details.

Comment: nice, i used AddRedirectToNonWwwPermanent() instead and I therefore had to also update my DNS and cert bindings